# Gnome doc and top bar background

Tags: ubuntu-dock

I have disabled ubuntu doc extention. I have i installed dynamic panel transparency. Normally my top have a dynamic background. But when i open workspace or application grid i see top bar and gonme doc have no background. I want to get background in both of them. My gnome shell theme is flat remix.
[image: desktop]

[image: workspace]
[image: appgrid]

Answer (score 0):

You are not having a top bar background because of the same reason, you have installed Dynamic Panel Transparency, and when you open overview, it will not show you a background